# Is it Possible to Run Multithreaded Tasks in Foundry?

Tags: testing, foundry, performance

I'm looking to run custom tasks/functions in parallel while using Foundry. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding if there's a way to use Foundry's fuzz testing capabilities to achieve multithreading.

For instance, in a typical multithreading scenario, you might have a function that takes a task ID and some task data, and this function would be called multiple times but executed on different threads in parallel. Is it possible to implement something similar in Foundry? In my understanding, Foundry uses multithreading to speed up fuzz test execution.

Here's a skeleton of what I imagine this might look like in a Forge fuzz test adapted to run a custom task:

```
contract MultiThreadTest is Test {
    // ...
    function setUp() public {
      // alternatively instead of passing taskData to testFuzz_CustomTask
      // taskData is initialized here for each taskId and stored in a storage array
      // testFuzz_CustomTask then fetches its taskData from the storage array using the index which is it's taskId
    }

    function testFuzz_CustomTask(uint256 taskId, bytes calldata taskData) public {
        // Custom logic here
        // ...
    }
}
```

Has anyone had experience with running custom tasks in parallel in Foundry? If so, could you provide some guidance and examples?